# Mahout Clustering and descrete values

Tags: mahout

I have data that has some discrete fields, or to put it in another way, enumerated values. For example, in my data I have a field like 'deviceType' that can take values like "Handheld" and "Desktop". Other string attributes may be urls. However, they inherently lack the notion of distance, and thus cannot be 'vectorized'. Also, Some of them are extremely important and meaningful. How can I incorporate them into the clustering procedure?

One solution I thought about is to split them into new boolean fields (dimensions). Is there a way to represent this in Mahout?

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Other option could be to have your own program generating sparse vectors, which can be given as input to mahout for clustering. 
e.g., input:

```
www.domain1.com/page1
www.domain1.com/page2
www.domain2.com/page1
```

we can split above urls into host, path, parameters like this

```
www.domain1.com page1
www.domain1.com page2
www.domain2.com page1
```

we can have dictionary with string, integer key-value pair like below

```
(www.domain1.com,  1)
(page1, 2)
(page2, 3)
(www.domain2.com, 4)
```

and sparse vectors like below

```
{1:1.0, 2:1.0}
{1:1.0, 3:1.0}
{4:1.0, 2:1.0}
```

The above can be given as input to mahout for clustering.